# State wise data of country and city

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have these tables:

[image]

Expected Output: 
[image]

Comment: Don't fotograph your computer screen. Add formatted text instead.

Comment: Why have you tagged 2012 and 2008? What are you actually using?

Comment: Alsoz what have you tried, and why didn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

Using simple join you can achieve it:

```
select s.name,c.name,ci.name from @state s
join @Country c
on s.countryid = c.id
join @city Ci on ci.stateid=s.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple left joins will work for you:

```
SELECT 
    S.Name AS State, 
    C.Name AS Country,
    CT.Name AS City
FROM 
    State S 
LEFT JOIN Country C 
    ON C.Id = S.Country_Id 
LEFT JOIN City CT
    ON CT.StateId = S.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Using join you can achieve it.

```
select ,b.name a.name,c.name Country as a inner join State as b on a.id=b.CountryID inner join City as c on c.StateId=b.id
```